# How would a "universal language field" work?

Tags: science-fiction, aliens, language, interspecies-relations, neuroscience

Looking to work with the topic of interspecies translation, covering a very wide variety of alien types and biologies, with a "universal translator"—but rather than a universal translation *gadget* or something otherwise individually used (like the Babel fish), I'm looking to figure out how an AREA could provide universal translation via having everyone within speaking the same "universal language", which sounds like the listener's native language to them. So two interconnected things to work out here: how would a universal language work for such a wide variety of species (some may not have the same vocalization types/ability as others, some may not use verbal language, etc.) and how would a "translation field"—like some sort of physical electric field, or a gas/chemical that affects the language centers of any brain under its influence—actually work?

One thought I've considered is the Universal Language, existing for the purpose of widespread shared communication, would have multiple forms/varieties within it, so that an individual may only communicate using one type but can understand any version of it that they perceive. (Think of how some English concepts can be communicated as a verbal word or another type of sound or a physical gesture; a character may only be able to speak a certain word in their variety of the Universal Language, but understand it whether it takes the form of a squeak, a vibrating low frequency, a binary series of beeps, a multisyllabic word, etc.). To the listener, of course, these wouldn't be distinguishable because all of them would SOUND as if the other party is already speaking their native language. Would this form be compatible with an interspecies language that isn't actively learned, but "instilled" by the universal translation field? Would a gas/chemical or a physical field be able to alter or "break down" the language function of a user's brain to do something like that?

Comment: The problem with translation is that there is no such as lossless translation, and there cannot be. Different languages divide the world in different ways, and there is simply no way to map the words and phrases of one language into another without accepting the loss of some information and the unavoidable insertion of spurious information. (For a trivial example, consider the verbal aspects of English, which *have to* be lost when translating into a Romance language; and when translating from a Romance language into English, a verbal aspect *has to* be manufactured out of nothing.)

Comment: your only option is magic, a translator has to understand both languages for anything but a sloppy translation.

Comment: Does appear to be a duplicate of that linked question.

Comment: I'm going to break the trend and vote to close as Needs More Focus. I apologize that you've stumbled upon a growing irritation on this Stack, but the idea that someone could explain how a fictional, fanciful, frankly magical system could "actually work" is... well... *it doesn't work.* You're not just asking us to explain the technology behind your clever idea, your also asking us to invent the technology need to design and build your clever idea, and a great deal more, because all of that is required to explain how something "actually works." (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... I'm willing to retract my vote if you can ask a specific, clear, and detailed question about a problem that's stopping you from moving forward with your Area-of-Effect translator. Why does "Hartwell stepped away from the jabbering alien long enough to tap the controls activating his language translator. The room hummed gently as the field Hartwell could never quite understand interpreted brain patterns, cultural responses, behavioral irrationalities, and settled on a way to help both he and the alien understand each other. A moment later Hartwell was surprised to clearly (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... hear the question, 'Do you want cream with your coffee?' which was the very last thing Hartwell expected the vociferous alien to be saying." *not work for you?* What does "actually work" mean to you? Explaining the operation of the translator is not really a worldbuilding problem. Understanding why you need to explain it, that is a worldbuilding problem. So, please help us understand... why do you need this level of detail?

Comment: The linked answer is not a duplicate, as this question specifically wants a field, and not a drone, personal computer or babelfish style answer. That said, I'm not sure such a thing can exist short of literal magic. *That* said, I'm not opposed to leaving questions like this open in case anyone else has better ideas. This seems like another case of "Well I can't think of a good answer so VTC". The question is clear, focused, and well-explained. And sometimes the legitimate answer could be "it can't exist". That doesn't make a question bad or close-worthy, though.

Answer (score 0):

## Have an AI manage it.

Have a super advanced computer which has a record of every language manage all the translation. The AI can have sensors which can detect sound, smell, motions, radio waves, whatever the species uses for communication. It then automatically translates the language into everyone's own language.

The translation field will be a cloud of nanites that surrounds everyone and both prevents any cross species infections and monitors all language use to translate it for people.

Reading people's brains is unnecessary and hard. Just have a bot do all the translation for them.

## Have a very strong central race impose common language laws

Just as America imposed English on the world, in your world some fairly strong alien race imposed their own language on the world. If you wanted to trade, you needed to speak it. This means that most languages have a lot of influence from that imposed language. While they may speak in their individual ways, translation and idioms and such tend to be fairly similar so most people can understand each other through a translation.